# Aborted (core dumped) with *** Error in `python3.6': corrupted size vs. prev_size: 0x0000000000e018e0 ***

Tags: c, python-3.x, swig, coredump

I am trying to wrap a basic c code to python3 using swig. I'am taking a string of length 3000{0,1} converting it to integer array terminating it to length 1000 and returning back as a string. 
The c code is:

`swig1.c`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int *bob;

static inline void *MallocOrDie(size_t MemSize)
{
 void *AllocMem = malloc(MemSize);

 if(!AllocMem && MemSize)
 {
    printf("Could not allocate memory!");
    exit(-1);
 }
 return AllocMem;
}
int* strtoint(char *input)
{

  int j;
  char *bsource;
  char *dest;

  int bit_len=strlen(input);
  bsource=input;

  dest=MallocOrDie(bit_len*sizeof(char)); 
  bob=MallocOrDie(bit_len*sizeof(int));
  for( j=0;j<bit_len;j++,bsource++)
  {       
    bob[j]=atoi(strncpy(dest, bsource, 1));    //converts to integer
   }

  return bob;
 }
 char* exposekey(char *bits)
 { 
 int i;  
 int  *bob_b;
 char *str;
 int exposed_code=1000;
 int bit_len=strlen(bits);
 bob_b=MallocOrDie(bit_len*sizeof(int)); 
 str=MallocOrDie(exposed_code*sizeof(char));   
 bob_b=strtoint(bits);
 for(i=0;i<exposed_code;i++)
 {
  str[i]=bob_b[i]+'0';
  }
  str[exposed_code]='\0';

  return str;
 }
```

My interface file is :

`swig1.i`

```
%module swig1
%{
char* exposekey(char *bits);
%}
char* exposekey(char *bits);
```

what I did to compile these using swig wrapper is:

```
swig -python -py3 swig1.i
gcc -fPIC -c swig1.c swig1_wrap.c -lm -I/usr/include/python3.6
ld -shared swig1.o swig1_wrap.o -o _swig1.so
```

I have a test code that generates 3000 random char{0,1} and invokes the python module `swig1.exposekey(<str>)`. I get the output (terminated string of length 1000) but with an Aborted core dumped after the output. I am unable to figure out why.

I am using python3.6, swig3.0 on ubuntu 16.04.

output:

```
1011101011001110010001101101000110100000010011100010010000000001111011110111001001011000110011100011010001001010101011000111100000010101101111000101101000011000000101000010111110010011010110001110101011011010101011001011101001001000110111000010000111110000110001110101110000000010010110011101011001001001011010100000010100011000001011110011111000110001010000101001101001011010001011101001000100111011100011100111110111011100001011111101010001011001010110101111000001011110010100011111100000000101001001110010011100010010001010011010010110111001001111010001001110110110001011111010010111000100011001101100011110000110001001101110110110100010110000110111110100001000111101110101101000101011010101110111010110001100001110101010011101001010101100101001100010011111101100001011000000001111011011111110110110100110011110010110101100001010001001101000111110011110011010110100000100011101101111011011001100101011001001001110001001011010000011000011011100101011100110111011010111000010010001111111010111100101
    *** Error in `python3.6': corrupted size vs. prev_size: 0x000000000224e7c0 ***
    ======= Backtrace: =========
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f38ba0817e5]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x80dfb)[0x7f38ba08adfb]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f38ba08e53c]
    python3.6[0x4f93b7]
    python3.6[0x5153c2]
    python3.6[0x53585a]
    python3.6[0x4dd6af]
    python3.6(_PyGC_CollectNoFail+0x27)[0x5eb657]
    python3.6(PyImport_Cleanup+0x22f)[0x5910ef]
    python3.6(Py_FinalizeEx+0x5c)[0x5e4c3c]
    python3.6(Py_Main+0x392)[0x5eaea2]
    python3.6(main+0xe9)[0x4d2fb9]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f38ba02a830]
    python3.6(_start+0x29)[0x5e3409]

======= Memory map: ========
00400000-007df000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3676651 /usr/bin/python3.6
009de000-009df000 r--p 003de000 08:01 3676651 /usr/bin/python3.6
009df000-00a7b000 rw-p 003df000 08:01 3676651/usr/bin/python3.6
00a7b000-00aad000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
0219c000-02283000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  [heap]
7f38b4000000-7f38b4021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f38b4021000-7f38b8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f38b9207000-7f38b921d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 7868921  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f38b921d000-7f38b941c000 ---p 00016000 08:01 7868921  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f38b941c000-7f38b941d000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 7868921   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
```

Comment: The first instance of undefined behavior is at `atoi(strncpy(dest, bsource, 1))`. `strncpy` is not a string function and should not be used. In this case it will not NUL-terminate `dest`, so `atoi` goes off and reads uninitialized memory. If you just want to convert a single digit to its numeric value, use `input[j] - '0'`.

Comment: Memory leak: `dest` is never freed.

Comment: Memory leak: `bob_b=MallocOrDie(...); bob_b=...`.

Comment: Why the h\*ck is `bob` a global variable?

Comment: Undefined behaviour: `str[exposed_code]='\0';` writes out of bounds.

Comment: Undefined behavior: `bob_b[i]` reads out of bounds. `i` is bounded by `exposed_code`, which is hardcoded to `1000` regardless of what `bits` is.

Comment: MallocOrDie can still return a null pointer for `bitlen == 0`...

Comment: Two things wrong with `printf("Could not allocate memory!");`: Lines must be terminated by `"\n"`, and error messages should go to `stderr`, not `stdout`.

Comment: `exit(-1);` is invalid: Unix exit codes must be in the range `0 .. 255`.

Comment: >Why the h*ck is bob a global variable?    That is because it has to be used in another function of the same module.

Comment: Thank you so much, have changed all of those points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression `strncpy(dest, bsource, 1)` contains a *serious* flaw.

From [this `strncpy` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy):

> If count is reached before the entire array src was copied, the resulting character array is not null-terminated.

With you passing `1` as the "count", it will *always* be reached before the source string terminator is found, and the destination will *not* be terminated. That will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your call to [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) as it will look for the terminator to know when the string ends.

If you want to convert a single digit from a character to its corresponding integer value, there is a much simpler (and safer) way:

```
bob[j] = bsource[j] - '0';
```

This works because all digits are guaranteed to be contiguously numbered in any encoding by the C specification. So if `'0'` is e.g. `48` (like it is in [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii)) then e.g. `'3'` *must* be `51`. And `'3' - '0'` is then equal to `51 - 48` which is `3`.

---

You also have some serious memory leaking:

```
bob_b=MallocOrDie(bit_len*sizeof(int)); 
bob_b=strtoint(bits);
```

First you allocate memory and make `bob_b` point to it, then you (in the `strtoint` function) allocate *new* memory and make `bob_b` point to *that* memory. That means you lose the original memory allocated for `bob_b`.

It also means you have *two* pointers pointing to the same memory, both the local `bob_b` *and* the global `bob`. If you pass both `bob_b` and `bob` to `free` you attempt to free the same memory twice, which is not allowed and again will lead to *undefined behavior* (and quite often to crashes similar to yours).

And if you call any of your functions more than once, you will leak memory like an open barn door will leak unchained cattle.

I suggest you learn how to use tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or similar memory debuggers.